# Cannot fetch images taken by camera from Gallery

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-gallery, picasso

I am trying to fetch image from the gallery using the following code:

```java
private void initGalleryFetchImage() {
    Intent i = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        LOGI(TAG, "picturePath: " + picturePath);
        if (picturePath.startsWith("http")) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(picturePath).into(iv);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(new File(picturePath)).into(iv);
        }
    }
}
```

I can retrieve all the images except the one that were taken
and stored by the camera application.

```
[☓] picturePath: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141223_102304.jpg

[✓] picturePath: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/...f3rf3.jpg
[✓] picturePath: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/IMG_13280625132331.jpeg
[✓] picturePath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20140521_232443.jpg
[✓] picturePath: /storage/emulated/0/LINEcamera/2014-04-12-19-47-52_deco.jpg
[✓] picturePath: /storage/emulated/0/foursquare/foursquare/1403867797152.jpg
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you set permission in `androidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: how you stored captured image ??

Comment: I have set the permissions correctly.
And I just took a picture from the camera app and tried to select it from the gallery image selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this


private void initGalleryFetchImage() {
    Intent i = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                try {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(selectedImage));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}}
```

Comment: this seems to fetch the image now but its also rotating it strangely!

Comment: @rishabhmhjn have u checked my answer ?

Comment: @kaushik replied to your answer

Answer (score 0):

in *onActivityResult(...)* use `selectedImage` which is an `Uri` for loading image

```
if (picturePath.startsWith("http")) {
      Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(picturePath).into(iv);
} else {
      Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(selectedImage).into(iv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed the http check and applied the URI directly to Picasso, but the problem remains the same

Comment: please check that `else` portion is executed.

Comment: yes, I kept that portion in the code as the first one wasn't necessary anymore